# Always select first item listbox vb.net

Tags: vb.net

The title says it.

Is it possible to always select the first item in a listbox?

I prefer not to use `listbox1.selectedindex = 0` or something like that

because i have loads of `listbox1.items.add` etc. and that would just make the code bigger.

so is there an option in a listbox or something..??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

```
listbox1.SelectedIndex = 0
```

This is your best bet. You can also try `.SelectedValue` but that won't help if you're trying to get "less code". You should bite the bullet on this one and just use `SelectedIndex`. I dont think any alternative is going to be so much better to make it worth the effort.